# Why I can manipulate dynamic matrix without reference

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference

Let it be a create function for a dynamical allocated array:

```
void create(int *&a, int dim){
    a=new int[dim];
    for(int i=0;i<dim;i++){
    a[i]=i+1;
}
```

Here, I need reference (`&`).
Now, I have a create function for a dynamical allocated matrix:

```
void create(int **&a,/* int**a, */ int lines,int rows){
   ...
}
```

I saw that reference is optional for dynamical allocated matrix create function. Why?

Comment: "I saw that reference is optional..." - Prove it. Show the code that builds the array of pointers *without* passing `int **a` by reference.

Comment: Encountering *reference to pointer* and *reference to pointer to pointer* kind of complication, it is time to start feeling **they deserve classes**.

Comment: You should explain what exactly you mean with "optional".

Comment: You probably saw that in a place that didn't explain very well. Many online tutorials can confuse even an expert.

Answer (score 1):

You need reference if you want to allocate the "outer" array - lines. Without it, you can allocate only "inner" arrays - rows (if "outer" array has been already allocated). So in your case, reference is mandatory.

```
void create(int **a, int lines, int rows)
{
    a = new int*[lines]; // passed pointer to 'a' will point to an old address

    for(int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
        a[i] = new int[rows];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the pointer passed to a function inside the function, it *needs* to be passed by reference.

So no, the reference is *not* optional in your case. Wherever you saw that it's optional, was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I'm sorry.
I saw that refference in assignValues function isn't necessary so I thought that it is unnecessary for the create function, too.
Thank you all for replies. 
Again, I'm sorry.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

void create(int **&a, int lines, int rows){
    int i;
    a = new int*[lines];

    for (i = 0; i < lines; i++){
        a[i] = new int[rows];
    }
}
void assignValues(int **a, int lines, int rows){
    int i,j,k = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < lines; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < rows; j++){
            a[i][j] = k;
            k++;
        }
    }
}

void print(int **a, int lines, int rows){
    int i, j;
    cout << "Matrix is: "<<endl;
    for (i = 0; i < lines; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < rows; j++){
            printf("%3d",a[i][j]);
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int lines = 5;
    int rows = 4;
    int **a = 0;
    create(a, lines, rows);
    assignValues(a, lines, rows);
    print(a, lines,rows);

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```